# ajax retornando branco

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

eu mais uma vez aqui. Vamos lá rs.

Bom, meu problema esta sendo o seguinte:

Estou passando valores para meu metodo no php via ajax, porém eles nao esta me retornando nada, fiz alguns teste e ele estra travando na seguinte linha

**Vou postar o código do teste (onde ele me da retorno) e o que eu quero porém esta travando**

> Método PHP

```
public function listarCidade($id)
{
    $obj_cidade = $this->verTodos("est_id=$id");
    if( $obj_cidade )
    {
        $opt="";
        foreach ($obj_cidade as $key)
            $opt .= "<option value='{$key->id}'>{$key->cid_nome}</option>";

        echo json_encode($opt);
    }
}
```

Nesta linha:

```
$opt .= "<option value='{$key->id}'>{$key->cid_nome}</option>";

 -O problema está sendo apenas isso ( `$key->cid_nome` )
```

pois se eu remover este pequeno código ele me da o retorno porem sem nada escrito no

`<option></option>`

**O que fazer em galera ?**

Comment: `json` é para retornar array, seu código está criando uma `string`, então é só dar `echo $opt` e deve funcionar. Agora se está retonando outra coisa, tem que postar o código de requisição do ajax e também os dados da página html que ele está pegando.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHHA, resolvido amigo!

Comment: Mudei meu retorno para html, por ser uma simples string o retorno, não sabia que tinha este conflito pelo fato de sempre dar certo assim. Vou prestar mais atenção, uma experiancia amais adquirida hoje. MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: @lvcs podes juntar uma resposta?

Comment: Obrigado poe kembrar,  vou postar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json é para retornar array, seu código está criando uma string, então é só dar echo $opt e deve funcionar.

Agora se está retonando outra coisa, tem que postar o código de requisição do ajax e também os dados da página html que ele está pegando.